# Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://localhost:3000/

Tags: node.js, angular, express, cors

SOLUTION: It turns out I needed to change **https**://localhost:3000, to **http**://localhost:3000. (My follow-up question would be why this is the case, especially as my code worked for **https**://www.remoteserver.com/`).

---

I have a development server at `https://localhost:3000` and a production server at `https://www.remoteserver.com` (Node.js/Express). My client is at `https://localhost:4200` (Angular).

I fixed the Cross-Origin Request Blocked issue with `https://www.remoteserver.com`, using the code as below:

```
var cors = require(cors());
app.use(cors());
app.options('*',cors());
var allowCrossDomain = function(req,res,next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
  next();  
}
app.use(allowCrossDomain);
```

But using the same code for my development server `https://localhost:3000` I am still facing the CORS blocked issue, and I haven't been able to get rid of the problem.

Is there any reason that the code above would work for the production server but not for the development server?

Any ideas on a fix or what I should try next?

Many thanks!

Comment: One idea here: [Allow CORS with localhost in Chrome](https://williambert.online/2013/06/allow-cors-with-localhost-in-chrome/).

Comment: Yes, thank you for forwarding that link ( CORS Error: “requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http…”). That provided the solution (i.e., changing **https** to **http**).

Comment: I Just googled it, was too lazy to try it out, but this should work, put the exact Hostname in the headers https://medium.com/@alexishevia/using-cors-in-express-cac7e29b005b

Answer (score 7):

The three solutions, avoiding CORS problem

1. Allow CORS to server side
2. Use proxy server
3. Use JSONP

Try to use as the following way

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

Get know details [link](https://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html)

Comment: Thank you. It turns out that didn't work in this case . . .  the fix was to change **https** to **http**, but I very much appreciate your input and assistance!